# PayPal - How to refuse payments below a certain threshold?

Tags: html, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am selling a high volume product that costs a minimal amount per piece. ($0.001 USD each to be exact).

I allow my customers to purchase a one time amount of product or a recurring payment amount of product at their desired choice of USD per payment.

How can I limit my customers to only spending $10 USD or more per payment through PayPal? They limit it at $10,000 USD, can I limit it at $10 USD?

Right now, I am not processing payments of less than $10 USD, and recommending that customers do not, but it is still possible to make them.

The problem arises when a customer purchases $1 worth of product and paypal takes 40 odd percent of that payment due to per-payment fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe PayPal offers a setting for minimum allowed payment.  This is something you would need to handle on the server side.   It would be easy enough to do.   Just don't display the "Pay with PayPal" button unless the order total is $10 or more.

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately, they only impose their own limits, and forbid you to impose yours. Fascists.